# Apache URL rewriting, how to serve static html file but disallow direct access to it?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to serve /help using /static/help/index.html. This does it fine:

```
RewriteRule ^help$ /static/help/index.html [L]
```

The problem is, Google is somehow double indexing both URLs, /help and /static/help/index.html. I want to 301 the .html URL. I tried adding a 301 so it looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^help$ /static/help/index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^static/help/index.html /help [NS,R=301,L]
```

I ended up with a redirection loop!

How do I tell it not to apply the second rule when used internally? NS is not doing the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^help$ /static/help/index.html [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/static/help/index.html
RewriteRule ^static/help/index.html /help [NS,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This also solved the problem:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^static/help/index.html /help [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^help$ /static/help/index.html [L]
```